# FlinkKafkaConsumer082 auto.offset.reset setting doesn't work?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a Flink streaming program which read data from a topic of Kafka. In the program, auto.offset.reset is set to "smallest". When test in IDE/Intellij-IDEA, the program could always read data from the beginning of the topic. Then I set up a flink/kafka cluster and produced some data into kafka topic. The first time I run the streaming job, it could read data from the beginning of the topic. But after that I stopped the streaming job and run it again, it will not read data from the beginning of the topic. How could I make the program always read data from the beginning of the topic?

```
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("bootstrap.servers", kafkaServers);
    properties.put("zookeeper.connect", zkConStr);
    properties.put("group.id", group);
    properties.put("topic", topics);
    properties.put("auto.offset.reset", offset);

    DataStream<String> stream = env
            .addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer082<String>(topics, new SimpleStringSchema(), properties));
```

Comment: The parameter `auto.offset.reset` is used by `FlinkKafkaConsumer081` and not by `FlinkKafkaConsumer082`. Thus I am wondering how you can set it? Furthermore, possible values are "latest" or "earliest" (and not "smallest". Can you share your code?

Comment: Added code, is there a corresponding offset property in FlinkKafkaConsumer082?

Comment: What is `offset`? `offset = "smalles"`? Can it be that your topic no longer contains the initial data because you've exceeded the retention time? Could you check with the `kafka-console-consumer.sh` to read the topic from the beginning?

Comment: offset is a string "smallest". I checked with kafka-console-consumer.sh, the initial data is still in kafka.

Comment: Possible values for `auto.offset.reset` are "latest" or "earliest" ("smallest" is **not valid**).

Comment: It doesn't work with auto.offset.reset as "earliest".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read always from the beginning you need to disable checkpointing in your stream context.

Also disable it on the level of consumer properties:

enable.auto.commit=false or auto.commit.enable=false (depends on kafka version)

Another way:
you can keep ckeckpointing for failover but generate new group.id when you need to read from the beginning(just clean up sometimes zookeeper)

Comment: Hi, I couldn't make first way work. But the second way you mentioned always works.

Comment: it means offsets are saved in zookeeper(you can check that in zookeeper or by kafka Consumer Offset Checker). Your goal is to disable that. Flink’s Kafka consumer integrates deeply with Flink’s checkpointing mechanism to make sure that records read from Kafka update Flink state exactly once. Disabling flink-checkpointning should be enough. Provide full code how you setup your env

Comment: `StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();` There are only several enableCheckpointing APIs, but I don't call it in my program.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-2974 - they added offset commiter if checkpointing is disabled. It looks like you can't disable auto-commit, see changes for this issue - https://github.com/apache/flink/pull/1341/files